# vowpal wabbit for binary text classification setup

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am using vw-8.20170116 for a binary text classification problem.  The text strings are concatenated from several short (5-20 words) strings. The input looks like

```
-1 1.0 |aa .... ... ..... |bb ... ... .... .. |cc ....... .. ...
 1 5.0 |aa .... ... ..... |bb ..... .. .... . |cc .... .. ...
```

The command that I am using for training is

```
./vw-8.20170116 -d train_feat.txt -k -c -f model.vw --ngram 2 --skips 2 --nn 10 --loss_function logistic --passes 100 --l2 1e-8 --holdout_off --threads --ignore bc
```

and for test

```
./vw-8.20170116 -d test_feat.txt -t --loss_function logistic --link logistic -i model.vw -p test_pred.txt
```

Question:  How can I get vw to run (train) in parallel on my 8-core machine?  I thought --threads should help but I am not seeing any speedups.  And how do I control the number of cores used?

Using this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156722/vowpal-wabbit-best-strategy-for-short-text-data-like-titles-kewords) for reference.

Comment: I am not familiar with `--threads`. In normal mode, VW uses one thread for I/O and another for the rest. See these [slides](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Cluster_parallel.pdf) about parallelization with cluster. It could be applied even on a single machine, but I am not sure if it pays off with just 8 cores. Also make sure I/O is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Have you seen examples for this? I am not sure how to get ./spanning_tree.  Is that a script or is there a binary for that?

Comment: Unrelated advice: by running `--passes 100` with `--holdout_off` you're most likely severely overfiting your dataset.  Whenever you run multiple passes, I highly recommend letting `vw` stop when held-out data starts showing increased error (early termination). `--holdout_period N` can be used to control what portion of the data is held-out for overfit avoidance.

Comment: @arielf thanks.  That is certainly what's happening given that I only have 30k cases (1s) and 150k controls (-1s).  Can you please suggest a set of parameter values that I should start with?  This is the first time I am using vw.   And if I want to play with some parameters, which ones are good first choices?  Thx.

Comment: [spanning_tree](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/cluster/Makefile#L29) is a binary which comes with VW. It makes sense to use it once you have billions of training examples, not thousands.

Comment: I am currently running `./vw-8.20170116 -d train_feat.txt -k -c -f model.vw --ngram 2 --skips 4 --ksvm --kernel=rbf --bandwidth=1 --loss_function logistic --passes 100 --l2 1e-8  --threads`  and it has been running for over 9hours on a text classification instance with 180k examples.  Is that expected?  Is there a way (maybe different params) for me to figure out if `svm` is even the right choice for this?

Comment: Start simple. Drop all the complex algorithms (`--ksvm --kernel --bandwidth`) and it will run an order of magnitude faster. Don't use `--nn` without a good reason for it. Also: why do you use `--skips 4` is there any special relation between  words 4 places apart? The original question conveys an effort to minimize training-error.  To succeed in machine learning always focus on minimizing generalization error, not on minimizing training error.